# Не хочет работать Slick Slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Делаю все, как написано в документации, выбивает ошибки :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" alt="">
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.1.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался с проблемой.
Во-первых, `"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"` я случайно подключил в скрипты, а надо прописать было в `head` через `link`;
Во-вторых, нужно было подключить еще одну ссылку на карусель с типом `js` : `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" alt="">
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.1.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```